# How do I recreate PowerShell $profile variable? It's empty in a custom Host

Tags: c#, powershell

If you implement a custom PowerShell Host with `System.Management.Automation` (SMA), all of the automatic variables are avaialable, except it seems that `$PROFILE` is empty. How would one go about recreating it?

Is it always in UserProfile + `\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`? Or do I need to be worried about it being in other places?

To clarify, I only care about `CurrentUserCurrentHost` profile.

#### Details

Given this PowerShell script:

```
Write-Output "_Profiles_" 
Write-Output "CurrentUserCurrentHost = '$($Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost)'"
Write-Output "CurrentUserAllHosts = '$($Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts)'"
Write-Output "AllUsersCurrentHost = '$($Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost)'"
Write-Output "AllUsersAllHosts = '$($Profile.AllUsersAllHosts)'"
```

Running it against system PowerShell has the following output:

```
_Profiles_
CurrentUserCurrentHost = 'C:\Users\rob\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
CurrentUserAllHosts = 'C:\User\rob\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
AllUsersCurrentHost = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
AllUsersAllHosts = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1'
```

Running it with a Custom C# PowerShell Host (a `System.Management.Automation.Host.PSHost` implementation) shows:

```
_Profiles_
CurrentUserCurrentHost = ''
CurrentUserAllHosts = ''
AllUsersCurrentHost = ''
AllUsersAllHosts = ''
```

#### Background

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/667

This has been tested in PowerShell v3 / `System.Managment.Automation` (SMA) v3 but it could easily be proven out in other PowerShell versions.

Comment: It can be in other places. Running from ISE gives "C:\Users\David\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1"

Comment: I saw that ISE is different, but I don't really worry about ISE's profile. IMHO the important one is the main PowerShell profile setting.

Comment: What about launching the real PowerShell console and asking that to dump out the value? `powershell.exe -command "& {``$profile}"`

Comment: Not a bad idea. Starting up a PowerShell takes a hit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible fix, this is what I've come up with. However it does mean that `$profile` is always expected to be in the Documents folder.

```
var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.DoNotVerify);
var currentUserCurrentHostProfile = _fileSystem.combine_paths(documentsFolder, "WindowsPowerShell\\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1");

var profileFix = @"
if ((Test-Path(""{0}"")) -and ($profile -eq $null -or $profile -eq '')) {{
  $global:profile = ""{1}""
}}
".format_with(documentsFolder, currentUserCurrentHostProfile);

pipeline.Commands.Add(new Command(profileFix, isScript: true, useLocalScope: false));
```

This is done this way due to special accounts like LocalSystem that would not have a profile folder.

**Note**: `.format_with` is a string formatter, so the `{{` and `}}` you see will be converted to `{` and `}` when it finishes the string formatting.

Comment: I think when you create a custom host, it is your responsibility to provide a $profile value. Eg. PowerShell Console and ISE have different implementations. cf. the Host04 Sample (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the HostUtilities.cs class (like this https://github.com/anurse/NuGet/blob/master/src/VsConsole/PowerShellHost/HostUtilities.cs)

Comment: @DavidGardiner That example was not that good... It seemed to be missing the most important part of the example `Microsoft.Samples.PowerShell.Host.HostUtilities.GetProfileCommands("SampleHost04");` (the Location of this) :D

Comment: The NuGet source example though, that was pretty good. Thanks! I wasn't looking to implement a custom `$profile` though, I was looking to implement the same `$profile` value found in the main PowerShell shell. If the answer is yes, it is always the value of what I asked, then that is pretty much what I'm looking for. :)